# json conversion error c++ IsString failed

Tags: c++, json, deserialization, libcurl

I have data in a JSON object that I can't seem to get to.

> Error:
>
> ```
> > testGetprice3.o: testGetprice3.cpp:71: int getData(): Assertion
> > `document["success"].IsString()' failed.
> ```

I have tried switching the datatypes, it only errors.
How do I correctly access my JSON object data?

```
#include "rapidjson/include/rapidjson/document.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>

using namespace rapidjson;

struct myData
{
    std::fstream *file;
    std::string *str;
};

size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, myData *data)
{
    size_t numBytes = size * nmemb;

    if (data->file)
        data->file->write((char*)ptr, numBytes);

    if (data->str)
        *data->str += std::string((char*)ptr, numBytes);

    return numBytes;
}

//function to get coin data and perform analysis
int getData()
{
    int count = 0;

    //begin non terminating loop
    while(true)
    {
        count++;
        CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
        if (curl)
        {
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://pubapi.cryptsy.com/api.php?method=singlemarketdata&marketid=155");

            std::fstream file("/home/coinz/cryptsy/myfile.txt", std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::ate);
            std::string json;

            myData data;
            data.file = &file;
            data.str = &json;

            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &write_data);
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &data);

            /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */
            CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

            /* Check for errors */
            if (res != CURLE_OK)
            {
                std::cerr << "curl_easy_perform() failed: " << curl_easy_strerror(res) << std::endl;
            }
            else
            {
                file << std::endl;

                //begin deserialization
                Document document;
                document.Parse(json.c_str());
                assert(document.HasMember("success"));
                assert(document["success"].IsString());
                //std::cout << "The Last Traded Price is = " << document["lasttradeprice"].GetString() << std::endl;
            }

            /* always cleanup */
            curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        }

        //timer for URL request.  *ADUJST ME AS DESIRED*
        usleep(10000000);
    }

    return 0;
}

//Le Main
int main(void)
{
    getData();
}
```

Comment: Perhaps this problem is because the JSON library is doing what it should. The success member is an int, so why are you asserting that it's a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your JSON data, the `success` member is an int (as it is not surrounded by quote marks).

More info on JSON types can be found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_types.2C_syntax_and_example

If the `success` member was a string, the JSON data would look like this: `{"success":"1",...`

Therefore when you call `assert(document["success"].IsString())` it causes the error, as the `success` member is not a string, but an int.

Since the `success` member is an int, change the assertion to test whether it's an int - `assert(document["success"].IsInt())`

Answer (score 0):

You stated you changed datatypes, but did not state which ones you tried. From the URL you are using, success is being returned as `"success":1`, which is an `int`.

Change:

```
 assert(document["success"].IsString());
```

to:

```
 assert(document["success"].IsInt());
```